# Initialize list from array using a initializer list

Tags: c#, list, initializer

A base class have **readonly** field of type `List<SomeEnum>` which the derived classes will initialize. Now, there is a derived class in which I want to add the all the values of the **SomeEnum**. One way is to type all the enum values, but the enum is a little big, so is there any other way to do it?

```
public class Base
{
 private readonly List<SomeEnum> _list;

 protected Base(List<SomeEnum> list)
 {
  _list = list;
 }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
 public Derived() : base(new List<SomeEnum>() { Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)) }
 {
 }
}
```

(The above code would not compile, I believe intializers don't accept arrays.)

Comment: You may want to accept `IEnumerable<SomeEnum>` or `IList<SomeEnum>` in the base constructor for future flexibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have to cast the result of Enum.GetValues to the appropriate IEnumerable<T> type.  See here:

```
using System.Linq;


public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived()
        : base(new List<SomeEnum>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)).OfType<SomeEnum>()))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to import System.Linq.

Answer (score 2):

That won't work because the collection initializer calls `Add` with your argument, and you can't add an Array to a List using the `Add` method (you'd need `AddRange` instead).

However there is a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) for `List<T>` can accept `IEnumerable<T>`. Try this:

```
new List<SomeEnum>((IEnumerable<SomeEnum>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)))
```

Comment: This does not compile.  Enum.GetValues returns an Array, which does not implement IEnumerable<T>.  It is not a generic.

Comment: I don't know why this answer is being voted up.  It doesn't work.  See my answer for one that *does* work.

Answer (score 2):

As Mark wrote, there is a List constructor that accepts an enumerable, maybe you can leverage it the following (less coupled) way:

```
public class Base 
{     
  private readonly List<UserActions> _list;      

  protected Base(IEnumerable<UserActions> values)
  {         _list = new List<UserActions>(values);  
  } 
}  

public class Derived : Base 
{     
   public Derived() : base((UserActions[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserActions))
  { 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried passing the array of values in the constructor of the list, like this:

```
public Derived() : 
         base(new List<SomeEnum>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserActions))) 
{}
```

Comment: Arrays do not implement IEnumerable. So the code doesn't compiles.

Comment: @hab: Actually arrays *do* implement IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

```
base(new List<SomeEnum>(((IEnumerable<SomeEnum>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)).GetEnumerator())))
```

I got it working by casting the enumerator returned to the generic type (which List accepts.)